# Check browser window closed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a web page with a button that opens another window.

When the button is clicked and the new page is open, I disable the button (because a need only  one page is opened clicking the button).
I use `window.open()` and not `windows.showModalDialog()` because the user should work on both pages.

When the second page is closed I have to re-enable the button in the first page.

I' tried with something like this:

```
var win = window.open("SecondPage.htm");
// disable button        
while (!win.closed) {
    setTimeout('', 2000);
}
// re-enable button
```

But using the `while` loop slows too much the browser, so it's actually impossible to work on the first page...

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout('', 2000)
```

is NOT `sleep()`

Your while loop keeps turning, and will indeed consume all the CPU, thus slowing down the browser.

Better:

```
var win = window.open("SecondPage.htm");
// disable button        
setTimeout('enableButtonIfWindowClosed', 2000);

function enableButtonIfWindowClosed {
  if (windowClosed()) {
    enableButton();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout('enableButtonIfWindowClosed', 2000);
    //function recalls the function itself
  }
}
```

Comment: Talking about SLEEP... this could also be helpful: http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Comment: No, that suffers from the same problems: the loop keeps looping endlessly until a condition is met. CPU usage will remain high, and your browser will 'hang'. Read the article comments, some people mention it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could bind an event to the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) or [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) events:

```
win.onunload = function() {
    // re-enable button
};
```

But this would also be called if the user loads a different page in the window, so you still want to check `win.closed` inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle through javascript user will refresh the page 1.This will fail.So When use click on page 2 link make ajax call save in server the button to disabled and make button attribute of the button like

```
        //page 1 script
   var win = null;     
$("#link1").click(function(){
  $("#button_id").attr("disabled", "disabled");        
  //ajax to server and save like button1 is disabled
  win = window.open("URL2");
  win.onunload = function () {
    //enable the button 1
  }      
});


  //In the page 2 script
  window.unload = function() {
    //ajax to button is enabled
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Konerak's code doesn't solve the CPU and memory waste problem. When using `setTimeout`, you must use `clearTimeout()` too, otherwise the timer tics as long as the top.window is open. Fix the code like this:

```
var win = window.open("SecondPage.htm");
var delay;
// disable button        

delay=setTimeout('enableButtonIfWindowClosed', 2000);
function enableButtonIfWindowClosed {
  if(delay) clearTimeout('delay');
  if (windowClosed()) {
    enableButton();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout('enableButtonIfWindowClosed', 2000);
    //function recalls the function itself
  }
}
```

and more sophisticated:

```
var win = window.open("SecondPage.htm");
var delay;
// disable button
delay=setInterval('enableButtonIfWindowClosed', 2000);
function enableButtonIfWindowClosed {
  if (windowClosed()) {
    if(delay) clearInterval('delay');
    enableButton();
  }
}
```

No CPU consuming and no memory waste.